# PHP: Checking if string has both Letters + Numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

In PHP, how to check if string has BOTH basic letters and numbers as follows:

(caseinsensitive) basic letters must be ['A' to 'Z' only] ('á' or 'ã' or 'Ã', etc...not allowed)

```
"helLo" returns false // does not contain numbers
"3110" returns false // does not contain letters
"h3lLo" returns true
"héll9" returns false // é not allowed
"helLõ" returns false // õ not allowed
"h 3llo" returns false // because of the space
```

Keeping in mind that must have letters and numbers, is it is also possible to allow underscores '_' and dashes '-' ?

Edit:

This works but looks complex, any suggestions to add _ and - ? :

```
$var="hell1um";
 if (strcspn($var, '0123456789') != strlen($var)) {
     if (ctype_alnum($var)) { echo "1"; }
 }
```

Comment: echo preg_match('@[a-z]@', "hellõ"); // returns 1

Comment: Yes, because `h`,`e` and `l` are in `[a-z]`

Comment: $var="hell0";
 if (strcspn($var, '0123456789') != strlen($var)) {
  if (ctype_alnum($var)) { echo "1"; }
 }

I am trying to simplify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
/^(?=[a-z\d ]*[a-z])(?=[a-z\d ]*\d)[a-z\d ]*$/i
```

This uses positive lookahead assertion `(?=)` which ensures the string matches but doesn't consume the characters it matches. This means that two separate checks can be made.

It checks that between the start `^` and end `$` of the string:

1. zero or more of any valid character (alphanumeric or space) followed by one `[a-z]` character.
2. zero or more of any valid character followed by one digit.

As long as both of this checks are satisfied and the remaining characters are also valid, the string passes the test.

If you want to allow additional characters like underscores and dashes, you can add them into the valid character class `[a-z\d _-]`.

Comment: wowoo thanks, had to remove the spaces; yes with _- functionality is perfect! :)

Comment: this works: /^(?=[a-z\d_-]*[a-z])(?=[a-z\d_-]*\d)[a-z\d_-]*$/i

Comment: @user3162468 looks good. I would change my answer but then it wouldn't work for the data in the question (it wouldn't match the last example. Glad you got it sorted anyway.

Comment: my bad, last example should be false, ur 100% right! (question edited)